# SoapUI: ConnectException: Connection timed out:

Tags: rest, connection, soapui, connection-timeout

i try to send request via REST. 
I get success response when using firefox rest-client, 
but in SoapUI i get exception attached below.
How to resolve this issue? 
Thanks.

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   timed out: connect    at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.Socket.(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
>     at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
>     at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:202)
>     at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:123)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: It may be useful for somebody: issue doesn't occur if start SoapUI from ${SOAPUI_HOME}/bin/SoapUI.bat

Comment: I've got the same problem: I get a timeout, while the server responds quickly when coworkers try it. My settings are identical to theirs. The only difference is that I'm on a Mac while they use Windows. This is in SoapUI 4.5.1.

Comment: Note that there is also a per request timeout that overrides the global setting. In the left bottom pane: "Request Properties"

Answer (score 60):

Default socket timeout is set to 60000 milliseconds.
You can change it:

> File -> Preferences -> HTTP Settings -> Socket Timeout

Answer (score 23):

You can also set the value to 0 and then it doesn't time out.
Tested it with SoapUI 4.5.0

Answer (score 10):

You can also set timeout for your request, it's on left bottom `Request properties`, that helped me (SoapUI 5.4.0)

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I would try adjusting the socket timeout in SoapUI preferences.  SoapUI has a standard timeout of 60000 milliseconds.  I would try making that much larger to see if you have the same issue.  This has fixed a timeout issue for myself before.

You can also edit this setting directly in the soapui-settings.xml

```
    <con:setting id="HttpSettings@socket_timeout">120000</con:setting>
```

If this doesn't help, try asking on the [eviware forum](http://www.soapui.org/forum/index.php).

Comment: "SoapUI has a standard timeout of 60000"; are you sure? Because I have a timeout occuring at 10 seconds only and we did not set that value anywhere.

Comment: http://www.soapui.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1872 SmartBear support says its 60 seconds (60000 milliseconds).  Of course that was from 2009.  You can check the preferences, the forum post will show you where to find it in the documentation.

Comment: In fact I noticed there is a socketTimeout setting in the testCase Option as well: [forum entry here](http://www.soapui.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=10912&p=27494&hilit=socket+timeout&sid=9576267b5cb2f3a7d4b36f6beae52cbe#p27562). It is not very well documented...

Comment: This advice only helps if your server is very slow. If it works normally, the timeout shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from adjusting timeouts, if this issue still persists then it could be because few of the `plugins needed by SoapUI are not loaded`. Because these plugins are present in some other place that require permission to access.

If u check your logs u can find this trace :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
```

The `problem does not occur when starting the SoapUI directly from bin`

Also you can `run with Administrative privileges.`